# PHP Variables - Confused

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system, tinymce

I tried looking for a question like this everywhere on the site, but couldn't find it!

So at the moment I'm doing a little admin panel for someone, and I want to give them the option to edit their website title. Currently my title looks like:

```
 <title><?php $website_title ?></title>
```

I have my $website_title variable set up and working, but now I want to make it changeable in my admin panel.

**EDIT:** Is there a way to send something from a HTML text box, to my PHP variable        $website_title?

Thanks guys :)

Adam.

Comment: Tried `<title><?= $website_title ?></title>`?

Comment: the whole code makes very little sense to me. what is this $_GET['title']? how it is going to be used? is it custom title for the page or for the whole site? why you are using apparently PHP variable but without PHP tags and commands?

Comment: simple to store the title into database and fetch it on the home page. And the second option that you are using is to read your `.txt` file and write after changing the title.

Comment: Ok to help you guys out and make this more clear: I basically want to know how to get text from a HTML text box - and transfer it across to the variable $website_title.

Comment: @ Jogesh_p can you please explain more about that first option? It's appealing to me :)

Comment: what idea of databases you have? Do you use one on your site?

Comment: I've worked with them before - but that's just for setting up forums: it does all the tables for you. As of that, No - I don't have much experience with them, and No I am not currently using one on my website.

Comment: how many variables you are planning to let user edit in the admin panel? And... what else this panel for?

Comment: It's only basic, so just the one variable for now (haha is that bad?).

The admin panel also edit the pages - which is already fully functional and working with tinymce. That's not my problem. I just to learn how to do this.

Comment: isn't `config.inc.php` file supposed to be edited manually by the site owner as it can be assumed from it's name? What's the problem with editing site title as well?

Comment: This is for someone with no idea about html/css/php code. Thats why I need a nice admin panel so that can edit it with ease, and make it feel easy rather than going into the file itself. As for that file, it's just what I called the file where I have the $page_title variable. Honestly it's pointless, so I can movie it to my header if need be?

Comment: okay. I can assume you are able to use tinymce to get some text from the user and store it in a file, when you let a user edit his page. then I don't understand why cant you do EXACTLY THE SAME THING for the file named config.inc.php

Comment: Yes right but if I do that won't it also bring up the php code for that variable?

Comment: I don't want them to edit the PHP code they'll stuff it up - believe me. I just want to make it so its just the Variable Text that shows up in tiny mce

Answer (score 0):

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$website_title = file_get_contents('includes/'.$title);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to send something from a HTML text box, to my PHP variable $website_title?

There is but it makes no sense in the context of the rest of the question.
You have to store this text somewhere on the server (once)
and then read it every time you need it.

to get more certain answer you have to ask a certain question.

Only I can say that using GET variables is totally inapplicable here and storing single variables in a separate text files is apparently not the best idea.

however, if you need only this one single variable to be edited. you may store it in a separate text  file (NOT site-wide options php file!) using `file_put_contents()` and then retrieve it on the every page using `file_get_contints()` as described in the first answer.

Comment: Thanks mate. Yes I just realized that's a stupid way to do it.

Comment: Would it be a better idea to use MySql?

Comment: it is always a good idea to use a database (most likely mysql) to hold your site data.

Comment: ok.... So how would I use file_put_contents() with a text field and a save button?

Comment: @user use whatever you are using to save pages.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is :

step1 : (get value of a text box and send to a php file)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    var title = $("#title_textbox").val();
      $.get("title.ph?title=" + title , function(data){
      document.title = data;
    });
});
</script>
```

step2 : (store data to $website_title)

```
<?php

$website_title = $_GET['title'];

// and do everything you want ;)

?>
```

and for saving it via a link use : 
step1 : (Javascipt)

```
<sctipt>
function save_title() {
       var title = $("#title_textbox").val();
          $.get("title.ph?title=" + title , function(data){
          document.title = data;
        });
}
</scipt>
```

step2 : (html)

```
<input type="text" name="title_textbox"/>
<a href="#" onclick= "save_title()">save title</a>
```

and then you may create a function like `store_title_to_db()` and then give the $website_title to it.

good luck

Comment: Thanks man great answer. Can you give me an example of what the html text box code would be please? Is there also a way to - for example click save and then it saves the text?

Comment: ok , but some one get me a -1 :( is it good for you ? if is it , i send you a complete example ;)

Comment: okay, I remove -1 because it's the OP to be blamed for the confusion. but the answer is still useless to him

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel i continue editing cuz he said your asnwer is great for me , thank bro for your direction\

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with tinymce (that's the reason why i answer here), so i guess you want to get the editor content (which is technically not a textarea but a contenteditable iframe). This can be done easily using javascript using the following code:

```
var content = tinymce.get('id_of_my_tinymce_editor').getContent();
$('title:first').html(content);
```

You may use this code as a button action on your page, or do whatever else you like.
But keep in mind that your content will contain html tags which will get displayed in your title!! For your purpose a simple inputfield or simple textarea (without the use of a tinymce editor (which creates html)) might be sufficient. In this case or if you want to use tinymce and call `tinymce.triggerSave()` you just get the textarea. So you need to get the content of the textarea and set the title accordingly:

```
var content = $('#id_of_my_textarea').text();
$('title:first').html(content);
```

Comment: Thanks. So that code there sets up the tinymce on my admin page - how would I then retrieve it at "../includes/config.inc.php" ?

Comment: this is again a literal answer to some part of the question, however makes no sense in the whole question context.

Comment: spose I'm going with you again... :P

Comment: Your question lacks many important information. For example at which time do you want to let the user set the title? If you want to allow the user to change the title of the actual page the code i provided is the answer. If you want to use the title permanently you will have to use my code to get the content and send it to a backend script using ajax. Your backend script will have to take care of saving the content to a database. And in your script you will have to use php to get the content from your database and assign the content to your variable $website_title.

Comment: this is for the site admin, I believe. title supposed to be edited by site admin and then saved in the config.inc.php file.

Comment: In that case his backend will have to update the file. But getting correct answers has much to do with asking well defined questions. And providing as much information as possible regarding the use case. He could also use another file instead of that config file (or a database) and get the content from there.

Comment: Ok here we go. More explaining. My clients are a law firm. They went to edit the site every now and then, maybe change the title. Edit Pages etc. On all my pages - there is the $website_title variable in the <title> tags. In my backend - I want then to be able to update the site title whenever they want.

Comment: I'm new to PHP - thats partly the reason why I sound like a retard